# there is an string array A , and an string array B . I want to delete elements in A which are not in B

Tags: javascript, arrays

I think i messed somewhere, Here is my code.

```
var flag;
for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++) 
{
  flag = 0;
  for (j = 0; j < B.length; j++) 
  {
    if (A[i].indexOf(B[j]) != -1) 
    {
      flag = 1;
    }
  }
  if (flag == 0) 
  {
    A.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

It gives output not as per my need
Someone please Help me out

Comment: There is no `A` or `B` in your code.

Comment: what is your current output? Elaborate on `I think i messed somewhere`

Comment: find a typo: should be `everywhere`...

Comment: can you just give an example for A, B and desired output?

Comment: A=["sub","div"] B=["add","sub","mul"];

Comment: output:    A=["sub"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function which generates first an object with all characters as properties and take it as hashtable for the filtering of `array1`.

```js
function deleteSome(array1, array2) {
    var o = Object.create(null);

    array2.forEach(function (a) {
        o[a] = true;
    });

    return array1.filter(function (a) {
        return this[a];
    }, o);
}


var a = 'abcdefgh'.split(''),
    b = 'banana'.split('');

console.log(deleteSome(a,b));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the job like this;

```js
//returns intersection of multiple arrays
Array.prototype.intersect = function(...a) {
  return [this,...a].reduce((p,c) => p.filter(e => c.includes(e)));
};
var a = [0,1,2,3,4,5],
    b = [4,5,6,7,8,9];
a = a.intersect(b);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, array "a" should have only elements which are present in array "b".

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];

var b = [4,5,6];

var new_a = [];

a.map(function(v,i,a){
    if(b.indexOf(v) !== -1){
        new_a.push(v);
    }
});

console.log(new_a); //[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

By this way i can filter as many arrays as you want.

```
var a = ['A', 'A', 'R', 'S', 'M', 'D',  'E']
var b = ['C', 'X', 'D', 'F']
//you can add as many arrays as you want
/*var c = ['O', 'P', 'D', 'Q']
var d = ['R', 'D', 'D', 'Z']*/
var arrays = [a,b, /*c , d */];


var result = arrays.shift().filter(function(v) {
  return arrays.every(function(a) {
      return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
  });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```